# Node.js Express NGINX : static file paths break with name spaced proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, node.js

So I was accessing my server at `domain.com:3333` but just switched it it to `domain.com/nodeapp` using upstream and proxy pass in my nginx config. The redirect works just fine, but now the links to static files being used my index.html (/styles/style.css & socket.io/socket.io.ks) are broken and all that displays is raw html.

From index.js

```
app.get('/nodeapp', function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/styles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/styles')));
```

From index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

From .../nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
upstream nodeapp{
  server localhost:3333 fail_timeout=0;
}

server{
....

    location /nodeapp{
      proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
    }

....
}
```

How can I re-establish the link?

Note that in my index.js before the switch the first line shown was `app.get('/', function(req,res){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this was kind of tricky to figure out, but painfully simple.

```
location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
}

location /styles {
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
}
```

The paths that index.html links to must be set as locations in the nginx conf that prox_pass to the node server.

Comment: hmm, i'll try yours now!

Answer (score 1):

Add a trailing slash to your location and to the proxy_pass target and let your original index.js untouched. Your links however should point to /nodeapp/{something} in index.html.

```
location /nodeapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp/;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I took your suggestion on `proxy_pass` and reverted my index.js to only get `'/'`... the page is being served but my styles and socket.io are still inaccessible. In console I get this `domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` I tried changing the paths in index.html to nodeapp/socket.io/socket.io.js but still get the same errors.

Comment: @AllTheTime Post the full nginx configuration

Comment: here's everything https://gist.github.com/allthetime/3be90d230508bc7500dc

Comment: @AllTheTime So you are not serving any static resource from nginx ? What should serve the socket.io.js file ? If you modified the index.html paths and they aren't taken into account you have something cached in your browser.

Comment: No sorry, I was unclear, they were taken into account. Instead the error was 
`domain.com/nodeapp/socket.io... Failed to load resource`

And, no, at this point I am not. The way the socket resources are linked to is confusing to me... Because there is no folder that exists called socket.io where socket.io.js resides. It is actually deep in the node_modules file in a folder called socket.io-client. I can force style.css to load by making a direct link to its location with nginx, but this is very hacky, and doesn't work at all for socket.io.js because it has links that break using this method